# Поворот Объекта unity

Tags: unity3d

Сейчас объект point крутится в сторону мышки и только вокруг своей оси
Как сделать что б объект point крутился "вокруг" игрока.
Ниже попытался объяснить) слева как сейчас, справа как нужно сделать
[image: point]

[image: Красная точка наш объект]

Comment: Ok Google: [точка на окружности](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала добавь для point пустого родителя. Должно получится так:
[image: Иерархия]
У point поменяй позицию сначала на нулевую а потом подвинь его например по оси X на 5. Получается, что радиус окружности равен 5. 
Теперь возьми Parent и попробуй его повернуть по оси Z.
И ты увидишь, что point движется по окружности с радиусом 5 и центром в parent position.